# Virtual Host showing error 11001 even after chown and chmod

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create a virtual host to just test a basic html website.

Guest OS - Ubuntu 14.04
Host OS - Ubuntu 14.10

In the Host OS, I connect through a proxy server which requires me to enter a user ID and password. I have a bridged network in the guest OS and I am able to connect to the internet in it.

So far I have done these steps.

**1)** Created the `.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`by doing this 
`sudo cp 000-default.conf tasdikr-1081310234.conf`

Then I edited it by `sudo gedit tasdikr-1081310234.conf` to something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#---------- Changes made -------------------

ServerName www.tasdikr-1081310234.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@tasdikr-1081310234.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
ServerAlias tasdikr-1081310234.com

#---------- Changes made -------------------

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**2)** Made the directory through this

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo chown $USER:www-data /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234
sudo gedit /var/www/tasdikr-1081310234/index.html
```

Inside `index.html` I did something like this

```
<html>
  Welcome to tasdikr-1081310234.com!
</html>
```

**3)** After that I changes the`hosts` file in `/etc/hosts`

and after changing it looked something like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   tasdik

#---adding lines for my website---

127.0.0.2   www.tasdikr-1081310234.com  tasdikr-1081310234

#--------adding stuff done--------

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**4)** After that I added my site by running

```
sudo a2ensite tasdikr-1081310234
```

And restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It gave me a message like this

```
* Restarting web server apache2 
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name,using         
127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
                                                                            [ OK ]
```

**5)**  I entered the url `http://tasdikr-1081310234.com` and

`http://tasdikr-1081310234` but I keep getting the error `Error Code 11004: Host not found`

PS : I also tried changing the modes. So I tried

- `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`
- `sudo chmod -R 754 /var/www`
- `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

But it is still giving me the same error.

Any help guys? I have been banging my head on this for the past 2 days.

I have also referred this [Digital ocean - How to set up virtual hosts in ubuntu 14.10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache logs in the guest OS to see if you are getting any request at all

See if you can ping the guest OS.

Fix the ip address in the host file 127.x.x.x is the loopback address and probably will connect only to the host OS and not the guest OS ( unless you are ssh tunneling, if this is the case telnet to the ip address and port "telnet 127.0.0.2 80" to se if you can get a connection )